# How to compute $\int \frac{x}{(x^2-4x+8)^2} \mathrm dx$?

Tags: integration

Can someone help me to compute:
 $$\int \frac{x}{(x^2-4x+8)^2}\mathrm dx$$
And, in general, the type:

$$\int \frac{N(x)}{(x^2+px+q)^n}\mathrm dx$$
with the order of polynomial $N(x)<n$ and $n$ natural greater than 1?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Integration by partial fractions; how and why does it work?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20963/integration-by-partial-fractions-how-and-why-does-it-work)

Comment: @Peter This question is not a duplicate, and does not necessarily require partial fraction decomposition. (Nor did the OP ask to use it.) Even if used, the methods below would be needed. Why use it when the methods below (needed in any case) suffice?

Comment: @amWhy The OP asked for a more general case. The answers below don't answer that. I think it is a duplicate.

Comment: @AymanHourieh I agree with amWhy: This question is asking for a formula for the integral in terms of $N(x)$, $p$, $q$, and $n$.  The other is asking for information about partial fractions.  **Not** a duplicate.

Comment: @amWhy as Ayman says, I marked this as a duplicate because of the second (quite general) part of the question. Of course the first part can be done with a variety of methods, but my understanding was that generality for this question comes with partial fraction decomposition (in particular covered under case 5 of the answer I linked to). Still, in retrospect it would have been better just to post a link to the other question and not to have proposed the duplicate, so I apologize.

Comment: @anorton Do you have an answer to the OP's second question that isn't a subset of the generalized answered posted by Peter? We have generalized answers for a reason.

Comment: @AymanHourieh I do not, but that doesn't mean that no one does.  I don't know about complex methods, but I wonder if that could lead to further simplification.

Comment: @anorton If there is a method not mentioned in the general answer, it should be added there.

Comment: @AymanHourieh some methods may work for this particular case that *do not* work for the prior.  Insisting that *all* methods that work for this question will work for the generalized form is crazy.

Comment: @anorton Let's keep it civil, shall we? All what I'm saying is that the answers presented here are merely special cases of a general solution we already have on this site. The reason we have a generalized answer is precisely to avoid a proliferation of special cases that don't add value. Given how straightforward it is to apply the general solution to this case, I doubt that there is value in waiting for new methods.

Answer (score 5):

$$\int \frac{x}{(x^2-4x+8)^2} dx = \int\frac{x - 2 + 2}{(x^2 - 4x + 8)^2}\,dx $$
$$= \frac 12\int \frac{2x - 4}{(x^2 - 4x + 8)^2}\,dx + \int \frac 2{((x-2)^2 + 2^2)^2}\,dx$$

For the first integral, use $u = x^2 - 4x + 8 \implies du = (2x-4)\,dx$.

For the second integral, put $2\tan \theta = (x-2)\implies 2\sec^2 \theta\,d\theta = dx$.

Comment: See [integration by reduction formulae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_reduction_formulae). Scroll down just a little and you'll see this method applied to such an integral.

Comment: For all natural n, after  substituion we obtain something like $\int (\cos^2 \theta)^{n-1}d \theta$. This method seems widely general.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

As $\displaystyle x^2-4x+8=(x-2)^2+2^2,$

use [Trigonometric substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution) as $x-2=2\tan\theta$

Comment: Nice hint lab. :)

Comment: During the computation, we have to integrate $\cos^2x$, i.e. we have to find the integral of $\sin x \cos x=\tan x \frac{1}{1+\tan^2x} $. Only now, we can subsitute the upper expression.

Comment: @bleish, $$\int\cos^2x\ dx=\int\frac{1+\cos2x}2dx=\frac x2+\frac{\sin2x}4+C$$ and $$\int\sin x\cos x\ dx=\int\frac{\sin2x}2=-\frac{\cos2x}4+K$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: Ok for the first expression. but, the second? why another integration?

Comment: @bleish, $$y=\arctan\frac{x-2}2\implies \tan y=\frac{x-2}2,$$  We need to calculate $$\sin2y,\cos2y$$  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: ok, ok. we only need to calculate $\sin 2y$ . $$\sin 2y=2 \tan y \frac{1}{1+ \tan^2 y}= \frac{x-2}{2} \frac{2}{1+ \frac{(x-2)^2}{4}}$$. There are no integral $\int \sin y \cos y dy$

Comment: @bleish, $$\sin2y=\frac{2\tan y}{1+\tan^2y}$$